# Kafka - windowing between two particular events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to perform operations (e.g. aggregation) of different events occurring between two concrete events. E.g. A user clicks button 'A' and some time after clicks button 'B' and I would like to count how many events (from other topics) have been arrived during this time.

The general concept I'm facing in my application is that my events have duration, they are not single events happening independently at a given time. In the example, the click on button 'A' would be the start of the event and the click on button 'B' would be the end.

My problem is that the windowing process offered by kafka (tumbling, hopping, sliding, session) does not fit to my scenario. Is there any other alternative for implementing this in Kafka Streams? Any other framework as Flink or Spark that can handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about other frameworks but a generic windowing solution from KStreams will probably not work for your case.

However there are ways to make it work for you. I don't know how your keys are set up so I am going to make an assumption that in the key you can determine the user and if it is a "start" or "stop" event.

If you are willing to make a new processor you can easily react on a start event, gather events until a stop event and then send that batch on as a single record. Which is basically a window. You can combine this with your DLS code using [process](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorSupplier-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named-java.lang.String...-), that simplifies constructing the topology.

There is probably a way to do this by grouping the stream and aggregating a certain way but that might require changes to how your key is constructed.

Comment: Thank you @wcarlson! I will try your solution to check and come back here.
When you comment "There is probably a way to do this by grouping the stream and aggregating a certain way but that might require changes to how your key is constructed." Can you explain a little bit more to get better your point?